Как сделать всплывающее окно с информацией "О программе"?
Есть приложение, надо сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на эту иконку открывалось новое окошко с информацией "О программе".


main.py
import sys
from PySide6.QtGui import QKeySequence, QShortcut, QPalette, QAction
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QMessageBox, QMenuBar, QMenu
from design import Ui_root

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_root):
 def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.setupUi(self)

    self.btnSummer.clicked.connect(self.funcSummer)
    self.outSummer.show()

    self.btnWinter.clicked.connect(self.funcWinter)
    self.outWinter.show()

    self.createMenuBar()
    self.createActions()

 def createMenuBar(self):

    self.menuinfo = QMenu(self.menuBar)
    self.menuinfo.setObjectName(u"menuinfo")

 def createActions(self):

    self.newAction = QAction(self)
    self.newAction.setText("info")

if __name__ == "__main__":
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = MainWindow()
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())

design.py
from PySide6.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QMetaObject, QRect, QSize, Qt)
from PySide6.QtGui import (QCursor, QIcon, QShortcut)
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QLabel, QLineEdit, QMenu, QMenuBar, QPushButton, 
QTabWidget, QWidget)

import files_rc

class Ui_root(object):
    def setupUi(self, root):
        if not root.objectName():
            root.setObjectName(u"root")
        root.resize(560, 440)
        root.setMinimumSize(QSize(560, 460))
        root.setMaximumSize(QSize(560, 460))

    self.menuBar = QMenuBar(root)
    self.menuBar.setObjectName(u"menuBar")
    self.menuBar.setStyleSheet(u"background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);")
    self.menuBar.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 560, 22))
    self.menuBar.setDefaultUp(False)

    self.menuinfo = QMenu(self.menuBar)
    self.menuinfo.setObjectName(u"menuinfo")
    icon1 = QIcon()
    icon1.addFile(u":/icon/info.svg", QSize(), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
    self.menuinfo.setIcon(icon1)

    self.menuhelp = QMenu(self.menuBar)
    self.menuhelp.setObjectName(u"menuhelp")
    icon2 = QIcon()
    icon2.addFile(u":/icon/help.svg", QSize(), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
    self.menuhelp.setIcon(icon2)

    root.setMenuBar(self.menuBar)

    self.menuBar.addAction(self.menuinfo.menuAction())
    self.menuBar.addAction(self.menuhelp.menuAction())

    self.retranslateUi(root)

    QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(root)


Как вариант:
import sys
'''          Установите свои импорты
from PySide6.QtGui import QKeySequence, QShortcut, QPalette, QAction
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QMessageBox, QMenuBar, QMenu
'''
from PyQt5.Qt import *

# from design import Ui_root                     #  Установите свои иконки
class Ui_root(object):
    def setupUi(self, root):
        if not root.objectName():
            root.setObjectName(u"root")
        root.resize(560, 440)
        root.setMinimumSize(QSize(560, 460))
        root.setMaximumSize(QSize(560, 460))
        
        self.setStyleSheet(u"background-color: rgb(107, 142, 35);")

        self.menuBar = QMenuBar(root)
        self.menuBar.setObjectName(u"menuBar")
        self.menuBar.setStyleSheet(u"background-color: rgb(34, 139, 34);")
        self.menuBar.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 560, 22))
        self.menuBar.setDefaultUp(False)

        self.menuinfo = QMenu(self.menuBar)
        self.menuinfo.setObjectName(u"menuinfo")
        icon1 = QIcon()
#        icon1.addFile(u":/icon/info.svg", QSize(), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
        icon1.addFile(u"ball.png", QSize(), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
        self.menuinfo.setIcon(icon1)

        self.menuhelp = QMenu(self.menuBar)
        self.menuhelp.setObjectName(u"menuhelp")
        icon2 = QIcon()
#        icon2.addFile(u":/icon/help.svg", QSize(), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
        icon2.addFile(u"Ok.png", QSize(), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
        self.menuhelp.setIcon(icon2)

        root.setMenuBar(self.menuBar)

        self.menuBar.addAction(self.menuinfo.menuAction())
        self.menuBar.addAction(self.menuhelp.menuAction())

# ?      self.retranslateUi(root)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(root)
    

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_root):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

# ?        self.btnSummer.clicked.connect(self.funcSummer)
# ?        self.outSummer.show()

# ?        self.btnWinter.clicked.connect(self.funcWinter)
# ?        self.outWinter.show()

# ?        self.createMenuBar()
# ?        self.createActions()

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        #action_about
        self.action_about = QAction(QIcon('about.png'), '&About', self)
        self.action_about.setStatusTip('About this App')
        self.action_about.setShortcut('Ctrl+F1')
        self.action_about.triggered.connect(self.func_about)
        self.menuinfo.addAction(self.action_about)
        
    def func_about(self):
        str_about = """Это приложение создано для ...
Разработчики:
blackpurpz

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1574999"""
        msgBox_about = QMessageBox()
        msgBox_about.setWindowTitle("About")
        msgBox_about.setText(str_about)
        msgBox_about.setWindowIcon(QIcon('Qt.png'))
        
        #msgBox_about.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
        msgBox_about.setIconPixmap(
            QPixmap("Qt.png").scaled(100, 100, Qt.KeepAspectRatio))
        
        msgBox_about.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok)
        msgBox_about.exec_()
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  
  
''' ??? 
    def createMenuBar(self):
        self.menuinfo = QMenu(self.menuBar)
        self.menuinfo.setObjectName(u"menuinfo")

    def createActions(self):
        self.newAction = QAction(self)
        self.newAction.setText("info")
'''
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())




Спасибо, но не помогло, сейчас обновлю вопрос

@blackpurpz что значит не помогло? Вы запустили мой код и получили ошибку? И что значит сейчас обновлю вопрос? Если у вас появились другие проблема - задайте новый вопрос. Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете,
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Да, попробовал, выдает ошибки.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Program Files\Python\Project\BenzConfig 0.4.1\app.py", line 141, in 
w = MainWindow()
^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "D:\Program Files\Python\Project\BenzConfig 0.4.1\app.py", line 50, in init
self.setupUi(self)
File "D:\Program Files\Python\Project\BenzConfig 0.4.1\app.py", line 12, in setupUi
root.setMinimumSize(QSize(560, 460))

TypeError: 'PySide6.QtWidgets.QWidget.setMinimumSize' called with wrong argument types:
PySide6.QtWidgets.QWidget.setMinimumSize(QSize)
Supported signatures:
PySide6.QtWidgets.QWidget.setMinimumSize(PySide6.QtCore.QSize)
PySide6.QtWidgets.QWidget.setMinimumSize(int, int)

@blackpurpz я вообще не понимаю зачем вы используете root.setMinimumSize(QSize(560, 460)) и         root.setMaximumSize(QSize(560, 460)), я бы их удалил или читайте документацию https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/PySide6/QtWidgets/QWidget.html#PySide6.QtWidgets.PySide6.QtWidgets.QWidget.setMinimumSize и используйте так root.setMinimumSize(560, 460)

@ S.Nick - root.setMinimumSize(QSize(560, 460)) сгенерирован Qt Designer, файл "design.py" это сгенерированный код с Qt Designer

@blackpurpz ну и что если код сгенерированный с Qt Designer ?

@ S.Nick Ваша цитата. " Никогда не изменяйте код, сгенерированный Qt Designer, НИКОГДА.
Создайте другой класс, который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения. "

@blackpurpz это цитата не моя, так говорят лучшие практики, если вы не знаете, зачем вы это делаете - не делайте этого. Я же у вас спрашивал зачем вы устанавливаете фиксированный размер окна вашего приложения? Текущий вопрос решен?

Давайте продолжим обсуждение в чате.

@blackpurpz, sorry, я же вам писал, если у вас есть другие проблемы - задайте новый вопрос, приложите код, который демонстрирует проблему и хорошо расскажите что вы хотите сделать.

@ S.Nick, Да все в порядке, я решил сделать немного попроще, просто в Qt Designer сделал доп. кнопки, добавил в них иконки и привязал к этим кнопкам функции, эта конструкция мне хотя бы известна и результат вполне устраивает, спасибо :)

@blackpurpz, пожалуйста.
